# Setting up ArcSDE for Oracle Spatial connection parameters?

Tags: qgis, enterprise-geodatabase, qgis-2, oracle-spatial, connection

Just testing out the new QGIS2 install here and trying to connect it to our huge SDE/Oracle spatial database. Im struggling with the connection parameters. Here is the connection properties to the databse from within ArcGIS10.1:

```
Instance = sde:oracle10g:g01l10g
```

I can't figure out how this maps across to the connection fields in the QGIS2 popup. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

You will by-pass SDE control and will get all of the oracle spatial tables.

[image]

Example: (DB/IP/Username has been changed)

> Database:Name of the Master database you are connecting to:
>
> Host:IP of database (must be unique)
>
> Port: Oracle is on 1521 (default)
>
> Username:username (must be a USER not DBA or superuser)
>
> Password:password (you MUST have password - no blank passwords)

Recommend:
To speed the QGIS2 table reading up:

For speed check Only look for users tables
and only existing geometry tables

Can take 10 minutes on large databases to read all the available tables.